# Restart a .NET Core console application

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a console application that updates classes during run-time. After  the classes have been updated , I need to restart (stop and rebuild) the application.
I know that it is possible to restart an ASP.NET Core application.

How would this be done in a normal .Net Core console application ?

Another questions is , if after updating my classes (which I use after the restart)  is it possible to build and load a new assembly with the updated classes during run-time ?

Comment: You mean it updates it's own classes in source code, so you want to stop it, re-build it, and then start it again? If so, then out of curiosity, why are you doing this? Perhaps there's a better way to solve the problem.

Comment: That may not be helpful to your direct question, but have you considered alternatives where your program doesn't self-modify? Could you store data to non-executable files instead? .NET is capable of loading new classes at runtime (or even creating classes at runtime), but self-modifying code is usually the realm of experts, and it is used extremely sparingly.

Comment: @RufusL Yes , that's my second question

Comment: @zneak I need to create "dynamic" classes to represent structures that change during machine learning using ML.NET

Comment: @znek I am able to modify the code at run-time , but the problem is loading the new classes at run-time. Seems like you know of a way to do this ? Can you please share.

Comment: @Kenneth, are ML.NET is using JSON or another words how your program interoperates with ML.NET dynamically?

Comment: @ArturMustafin I need to send classes to a prediction engine or function so that ML.NET understand the columns of my data set
This is how a class looks like : https://github.com/dotnet/machinelearning-samples/blob/master/samples/csharp/getting-started/Regression_TaxiFarePrediction/TaxiFarePrediction/TaxiFarePredictionConsoleApp/DataStructures/TaxiTrip.cs

Comment: While you can isolate assemblies using AssemblyLoadContext it cannot unload assemblies currently. Unloading support is coming in .NET Core 3 and is currently in preview. An example of [compiling and running updated code at runtime](https://laurentkempe.com/2019/02/18/dynamically-compile-and-run-code-using-dotNET-Core-3.0/).